# Add 3 rows to existing vba code

Tags: excel, vba

Below is vba code that I am using now. Edit details at the bottom.

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer
Range("a1").Select
'
iRow = 1
'
Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, 1) <> Cells(iRow, 1) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, 2).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

The above vba code I found (googling) in one of Stackoverflows questions that someone has asked, and it worked for my purpose.  However I cannot locate it to give information as to which question it arose from.

I am now using it and works great.  However I need more rows added. So I have to manually insert rows as I need them.  I would like to make the vba code do it for me.  Instead of adding 1 row after each grouped cell.  I need 3 rows added.  Could somebody help me edit the above macro to allow it to give me 3 rows rather than 1 row.

This is my first post and thanking everybody in advance.
GraceSarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the least invasive way to modify your existing formula to add 2 more rows

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim x as Integer
Range("a1").Select
'
iRow = 1
'
Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, 1) <> Cells(iRow, 1) Then
    For x = 1 To 3
        Cells(iRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    Next x
    iRow = iRow + 4
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, 2).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow in 3 min. Thank you very much.  I was trying to play with the numbers in the macro...but could not do it.