# Add 2 rows to existing macro

Tags: excel, vba, insert, rows

Below is macro that I am using now..edit details at the bottom.

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer
Range("a1").Select
'
iRow = 1
'
Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, 1) <> Cells(iRow, 1) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, 2).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

The above macro I found (googling) in one of Stackoverflows questions that someone has asked and it worked for my purpose. However I cannot locate it to give information as to which question it arose from.

I am now using it and works great. However I need more rows added. So I have to manually insert rows as I need them. I would like to make the macro do it for me. Instead of adding 1 row after each grouped cell. I need 2 rows added. Could somebody help me edit the above macro to allow it to give me 2 rows rather than 1 row.

Also, I need to seperate the rows based on the data in column E and not A, I've been searching for a couple hours and monkeying with the coding but I just can't get it to work, I'm fairly new to this and still learning.

This is my first post and thanking everybody in advance.

Comment: [Is this the prior question you were referencing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982706/add-3-rows-to-existing-macro)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you precisely want to achieve with that macro, but here it's how I would do it:

```
Sub AddBlankRows()

    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer

    iRow = 1 ' Row 1
    iCol = 5 ' Column E

    Do

        If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
            Range(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol), Cells(iRow + 2, iCol)).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            iRow = iRow + 3
        Else
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If

    Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Text = ""

End Sub
```